# Replacing Boom Mic Segment

Tags: boom-pole, repair, replacement, damage

My first boom pole was a very pretty Gitzo carbon fiber pole.  Loved that thing!  I think it extended to 12' or so.

I rented out my sound gear (I have learned to not do that any more) and they somehow "lost" the top segment of the pole.  Before I could get money for the lost part, the director robbed his roommates and fled to who knows where.

I got a new pole, and the old one has been in storage.

Has anybody ever damaged a segment of a boom pole and needed replacement?  Is it going to cost me more than a new pole just to get it?

I will email the company on Monday and see where that gets me.

Comment: Sometimes I really love our business. Robbed his roommates indeed. Sounds about in line with some of the directors/producers I've met. 

Comment: Seriously.  I'm just glad I got my gear back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking it to a local camera repair shop that can repair Gitzo tripods as some of the parts are shared.  Most repairs are cheaper than a replacement, even if only slightly.

Comment: @Iain Found a place that repairs Gitzo in town.  Yaaay!  Thanks!

Comment: Ehhh, scratch that.  Everybody says I have to go through Manfrotto directly...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to put out a message on some of the well known audio rental sites that also sell stuff on commission. ie www.locationsound.com Also, maybe try to communicate like you are doing now with other industry pro's on blogs like this and you might get lucky. I truly understand what it means to have a favorite piece of gear get broken or go missing because of other peoples irresponsibility. I used to know of a guy who hoarded pieces of gear in Montreal (cables, camera accessories, studio bits and bobs etc.) Unfortunately I have lost touch with him but a number of years ago, he was the go to guy if you needed something. I am sure there are others out there like him.

Good luck.